# Why is the hash value wrong?

Tags: c, hash, openssl, md5, hmac

I 've been trying this for a while and keep getting a wrong hash value. I know that it is wrong because I have checked it against online HMAC calculators

```
unsigned char data[]="data";
unsigned char key[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH]; 
MD5(data, strlen(data), key);   

unsigned char* t;
t=HMAC(EVP_md5(),key,16,data, 16,NULL,NULL);

for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", t[i]); //totally wrong value
}
```

Comment: Could you add what you would consider being a correct HMAC in this case?

Comment: Isn't HMAC - MD5 deterministic? By correct I mean the same value I get when I run this on an online HMAC calculator

Comment: With both the key and the data equal to "data"?

Comment: Are you really intending to use the MD5 sum of the data as the key? The key for an HMAC is supposed to be a constant, unrelated to the data.

Comment: True but this is testing to see if it works

Comment: You pass 16 as length of `data` whereas the actual length of `data` is only 4.

Answer (score 0):

To get a HMAC matching the online generators, it's a simple as;

```
unsigned char* data = "data";
unsigned char* key  = "key";
unsigned char* t;

t = HMAC(EVP_md5(), key, strlen(key), data, strlen(data), NULL, NULL);

for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", t[i]);
}
```

In your example, you're using MD5 on the key before calculating the HMAC, which is not what the online generators do. Of course, if your key or data are not regular null terminated strings, you need to replace the `strlen` calls with the actual length.